# Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: <mapping> element in configuration specifies no known attributes

Tags: hibernate, junit

while running junit test case giving error like 
     
    
    
      
        org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
        oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
        sr
        sr

Comment: Can you paste the configuration file of hibernate 'hibernate.cfg.xml'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem may be in hibernate **.cfg.xml file**.  Check whether there is any spelling mistake or not.
**default port number for mysql is 3306**. 
Your cfg.xml file should be like this. In this example i used mysql.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:port_number_of_database/databasename</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">your_username</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">your_password</property>
    <mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```